# Using Structs in Functions

Tags: c, optimization

I have a function and i'm accessing a struct's members a lot of times in it.
What I was wondering about is what is the good practice to go about this?

For example:

```
struct s
{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

and I have allocated memory for 10 objects of that struct using malloc.

So, whenever I need to use only one of the object in a function, I usually create (or is passed as argument) pointer and point it to the required object (My superior told me to avoid array indexing because it adds a calculation when accessing any member of the struct)

But is this the right way? I understand that dereferencing is not as expensive as creating a copy, but what if I'm dereferencing a number of times (like 20 to 30) in the function.

Would it be better if i created temporary variables for the struct variables (only the ones I need, I certainly don't use all the members) and copy over the value and then set the actual struct's value before returning?

Also, is this unnecessary micro optimization? Please note that this is for embedded devices.

Comment: Try both, and _measure_ how well they perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, indexing an array is not very expensive (only like one operation more expensive than a pointer dereference, or sometimes none, depending on the situation).

Secondly, most compilers will perform what is called RVO or return value optimisation when returning structs by value. This is where the caller allocates space for the return value of the function it calls, and secretly passes the address of that memory to the function for it to use, and the effect is that no copies are made. It does this automatically, so

```
struct mystruct blah = func();
```

Only constructs one object, passes it to func for it to use transparently to the programmer, and no copying need be done.

What I do not know is if you assign an array index the return value of the function, like this:

```
someArray[0] = func();
```

will the compiler pass the address of `someArray[0]` and do RVO that way, or will it just not do that optimisation? You'll have to get a more experienced programmer to answer that. I would guess that the compiler is smart enough to do it though, but it's just a guess.

And yes, I would call it micro optimisation. But we're C programmers. And [that's how we roll](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1m71m-LBqFQ).

Answer (score 3):

This is for an embedded system. So, I can't make any assumptions about what the compiler will do. I can't make any assumptions about word size, or the number of registers, or the cost of accessing off the stack, because you didn't tell me what the architecture is. I used to do embedded code on 8080s when they were new...

OK, so what to do?

Pick a real section of code and code it up. Code it up each of the different ways you have listed above. Compile it. Find the compiler option that forces it to print out the assembly code that is produced. Compile each piece of code with every different set of optimization options. Grab the reference manual for the processor and count the cycles used by each case.

Now you will have real data on which to base a decision. Real data is much better that the opinions of a million highly experience expert programmers. Sit down with your lead programmer and show him the code and the data. He may well show you better ways to code it. If so, recode it his way, compile it, and count the cycles used by his code. Show him how his way worked out.

At the very worst you will have spent a weekend learning something very important about the way your compiler works. You will have examined N ways to code things times M different sets of optimization options. You will have learned a lot about the instruction set of the machine. You will have learned how good, or bad, the compiler is. You will have had a chance to get to know your lead programmer better. And, you will have real data.

Real data is the kind of data that you must have to answer this question. With out that data nothing anyone tells you is anything but an ego based guess. Data answers the question.

Bob Pendleton

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the case in which you want to make a copy of a passed struct in C is if you want to manipulate the data in place. That is to say, have your changes not be reflected in the struct it self but rather only in the return value. As for which is more expensive, it depends on a lot of things. Many of which change implementation to implementation so I would need more specific information to be more helpful. Though, I would expect, that in an embedded environment you memory is at a greater premium than your processing power. Really this reads like needless micro optimization, your compiler should handle it.

Comment: I want to change the values of the actual struct object in the function (i.e. have it reflect upon the struct itself), that being the reason why i asked this question. Otherwise using a pointer is arguably better than creating a copy and using more memory. And yes it felt like micro optimization, but my superior told me to do it. heh

Answer (score 0):

In this case creating temp variable on the stack will be faster. But if your structure is much bigger then you might be better with dereferencing.